# Rails 5 using JQuery to run a method in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller action that runs a rake task when the user clicks a button. I want to try make jQuery/Ajax action this button once a timer runs to 0.

Here is the script for the timer countdown.

Thanks a million.

```
<script>
    var deadline = new Date("<%= @auction.end_time.strftime("%B %-d, %Y %H:%M:%S") %>").getTime();                                                      
    console.log(deadline);

    var x = setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var t = deadline - now;
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    // var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m ";
      if (t < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "AUCTION CLOSED";
    // Make JQuery action method to edit auction status
    alert("Auction closed")
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Controller

```
def check_auctions
    system "rake dashboard:fetch &"
    flash[:notice] = "Checking auctions end times and status"
    redirect_to admin_auctions_path
end
```

Routes

```
check_auctions_admin_auctions POST   /admin/auctions/check_auctions(.:format)    admin/auctions#check_auctions
```

Routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :auctions do
        collection do 
            post 'check_auctions', action: "check_auctions"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: i guess you want to make ajax call to `check_auctions_admin_auctions_path` every 1000 ms and then update something in html? am I right?

Comment: I'd like to just run the check_auctions_admin_auctions_path when the time gets to 0 and then refresh the page. The every 1000 ms is just to run the clock from what I can gather. If I can get the button to work once the t < 0 occurs that would be great. 

Once I understand the ajax call I can play about with how it's actioned I suppose. Thanks @blazpie